# Error when trying to persist a large object graph

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am getting an error when trying to call entityManager.persist() on a large object graph. Here is what I have. I am trying to persist RecordType which has the following definitions:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="recordType", cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST})
public Set<Form> getForms() {
    return this.forms;
}
public void setForms(Set<Form> forms) {
    this.forms = forms;
}

@ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST})
@JoinColumn(name="workflow_id")
public Workflow getWorkflow() {
    return workflow;
}
```

Workflow has the following definition:

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="workflow", cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST})
public Set<WorkflowState> getWorkflowStates() {
    return this.workflowStates;
}
```

WorkflowState has the following definition:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="states", cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST})
public Set<Form> getForms() {
    return this.forms;
}
```

Form has the following definition:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST})
@JoinColumn(name="record_type_id", nullable=false)
public RecordType getRecordType() {
    return this.recordType;
}
```

This references the same RecordType that I want to persist. What hibernate is doing:

```
DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - insert into workflow
DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - insert into workflow_state
DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - insert into form
```

When it does this insert into form, it is passing a null record_type_id. So I am getting:

```
 MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'record_type_id' cannot be null
```

Somehow hibernate is trying to persist the Form when the RecordType has not been persisted yet, and even worse, it's not even trying to persist the RecordType at this stage when it obviously needs it to continue. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Between `Form` and `RecordType`, which entity owns the relationship?

Add @OneToMany on RecordType if its not added already?

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "recordType", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
        public List<Form> forms = new ArrayList<Form>();

Comment: @ZahidM I guess Form owns the relationship. I have the OneToMany already defined on RecordType. I've added the definition to the question.